# XIB is not showing / loading the scrollview but the controls added via code inside the viewdidload being shown

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, pushviewcontroller

I have addded `UIScrollView` to my xib but it was not showing on to my view controller.

Also in the view did load method, I have added text boxes to the view controller. This is displayed when I push the view, but not the scrollview which I added inside the xib.

I tried to push the view in two ways

Way 1

```
SubscribedDetailedViewController *aDetailView = [[[SubscribedDetailedViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SubscribedDetailedViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:aPoemDetailView animated:YES];
```

Way 2

```
SubscribedDetailedViewController *aDetailView = [[[SubscribedDetailedViewController alloc]init]autorelease];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:aPoemDetailView animated:YES];
```

Also I placed the below code

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

The above function also gets called.

Why the scrollview which I added into the xib is not being displayed? But the controls added via code inside the `viewdidload` being shown.

Comment: How do you know that the scroll view isn't being displayed?  (Their appearance isn't usually obvious.)  Do you have it connected as an IBOutlet of your controller?  If so, is it being connected correctly in `viewDidLoad:`?

Comment: Give background color of scrollview and then check it..

Comment: yes i have set background but it is not being displayed. more over which one is right? pls tel me